To output syndrome measurement results
May I ask you a question about the following? GitHub - Infleqtion/qLDPC: Tools for constructing and analyzing quantum low density parity check (qLDPC) codes.
In the above code, is there any code that outputs the results of syndrome measurements for each code? With Pauli errors inserted.
Also, if there are any sample codes for decoding these, I would appreciate it if you could point me to where I can find them.
Is there anything else you'd like me to help with regarding this translation or the technical content of the email?
https://github.com/Infleqtion/qLDPC

I'm not familiar with this package, but from a quick look I see that the code outputs parity check matrices. Given a parity check matrix $H$ and an error vector $E$ (a pauli string in symplectic notation), the syndrome is given by $HE=s$.

Thank you for your response. I think I'll take a look at the code as well.
